# ATpy ImportError: No module named astropy.io

Tags: python, module, osx-snow-leopard

I tried to get atpy on python 2.7. I downloaded ATpy0.9.6 from

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ATpy/0.9.6

then tar it, and run:

cd ATpy0.9.6
sudo python setup.py install

things seemed to work well.

But when I tried to import atpy on python, I got always this error message:

**ImportError: No module named astropy.io**

More precisely,

```
>>> import atpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/atpy/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .basetable import Table, TableSet, VectorException
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/atpy/basetable.py", line 15, in <module>
    from . import registry
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/atpy/registry.py", line 164, in <module>
    from . import fitstable
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/atpy/fitstable.py", line 8, in <module>
    from astropy.io import fits
ImportError: No module named astropy.io
>>>
```

Could anyone help me to figure out the problem?

Comment: Do `pip install astropy` ; Reference: http://www.astropy.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the 'atpy' package depends on another package called 'astropy.io' that you are missing? Yes here it is https://astropy.readthedocs.org/en/v0.1/index.html

It happens that downloading the tar balls from pypi.python.org is the wrong way to install Python packages. The right way (though the Python docs explain poorly), is to run a command like

```
pip install atpy
```

This command will install your package and all its dependencies.

If the command `pip` is missing, you have to install it, which is ironically really complicated.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the solution was to install astropy

`pip install --no-deps astropy`